# Node startup failure: FileNotFoundException

Tags: cassandra

I'm having an issue that prevents me from starting Cassandra daemon.

I'm using Cassandra Community 2.1.4

I created my cluster several hours ago, and it was working perfectly until I rebooted the azure VM which is hosting this node.
My cluster uses password authentication.

Any idea ?

**edit** : I dont know if it is relevant, but I tried to drop a keyspace before rebooting, and it failed. (no, i have not tried to drop system_auth keyspace, in case you wonder)

Cassandra log file contains:

> ERROR [MemtableFlushWriter:3] 2015-04-14 13:42:54,359
>   CassandraDaemon.java:223 - Exception in thread
>   Thread[MemtableFlushWriter:3,5,main] java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /var/lib/cassandra/data/system_auth/users-473588ad9c7938be8b59e06c10456ba0/system_auth-users-tmp-ka-2-Index.db
>   (Permission denied)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.(SequentialWriter.java:80)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.open(SequentialWriter.java:109)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.open(SequentialWriter.java:104)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter$IndexWriter.(SSTableWriter.java:598)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.(SSTableWriter.java:135)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.createFlushWriter(Memtable.java:404)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.writeSortedContents(Memtable.java:343)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.runMayThrow(Memtable.java:327)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
>   ~[guava-16.0.jar:na]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore$Flush.run(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1092)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_76]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_76]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.7.0_76]

**edit2**

Several lines ago in log file:

> WARN  [main] 2015-04-14 14:06:59,068 CommitLogReplayer.java:139 - Encountered bad header at position 16 of commit log /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-4-1429010621980.log, with invalid CRC. The
>   end of segment marker should be zero.

Any way to fix that ?

Answer (score 1):

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/cassandra/data/system_auth/users-473588ad9c7938be8b59e06c10456ba0/system_auth-users-tmp-ka-2-Index.db (Permission denied)

This line says, cassandra cannot create `/var/lib/cassandra/data/system_auth/users-473588ad9c7938be8b59e06c10456ba0/system_auth-users-tmp-ka-2-Index.db` without permission. Check if subdirectories' owner is `cassandra`. If no, assign it to the right owner `cassandra` and restart cassandra.

`chown -R cassandra:cassandra /var/lib/cassandra/data/system_auth`